# Run my Wifi Atheros AR6004 (ath6kl) wifi dell 1537 ac Noob need help

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, atheros

Please give me a step by step method.

After a long search I found https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath6kl

It looks fine and I tried what it says but am stuck on this part.

> The driver is located in drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl. To compile
> the driver enable CONFIG_ATH6KL which is found under Device
> Drivers/Network device support/Wireless LAN/Atheros Wireless
> Cards/Atheros ath6kl support. Also enable CONFIG_ATH6KL_DEBUG to
> include all debugging code.

Can anybody help so I can run this?

I also looked at the firmware as my device does not show it anywhere.
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/download/stable

I used this discussion https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=241102&start=20
to install but no luck.

Main issue is I am unable to get anything to work in Linux also I don't have any knowledge of drivers.

My Wireless info is

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 23 Sep 2021 16:48 IST +0530

Booted last: 23 Sep 2021 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.11.0-36-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Sep 18 02:14:19 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, recovery, nomodeset, dis_ucode_ldr

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 114d:1000 Alpha Imaging Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 06cb:2819 Synaptics, Inc. Synaptics T Pad V 01.31
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5751 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211             1024000  1 mt7601u
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
dell_laptop            24576  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,dell_laptop
ath6kl_sdio            20480  0
ath6kl_core           167936  1 ath6kl_sdio
dell_wmi               20480  0
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
cfg80211              888832  3 ath6kl_core,mt7601u,mac80211
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
wmi_bmof               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 dell_wmi,intel_vbtn
wmi                    32768  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
video                  53248  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search TOTOLINK

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         759       1  0 16:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/D-LINK_DIR-615.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=D-LINK_DIR-615 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=D-LINK_DIR-615
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DIRECT-cW-FireTV_2d93.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DIRECT-cW-FireTV_2d93 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=DIRECT-cW-FireTV_2d93
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.11.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[ath6kl_sdio]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl_sdio.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Atheros AR600x SDIO devices
depends:        ath6kl_core
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath6kl_sdio
vermagic:       5.11.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[ath6kl_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for AR600x SDIO and USB devices.
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath6kl_core
vermagic:       5.11.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug_mask:uint
parm:           suspend_mode:uint
parm:           wow_mode:uint
parm:           uart_debug:uint
parm:           uart_rate:uint
parm:           ath6kl_p2p:uint
parm:           testmode:uint
parm:           recovery_enable:Enable recovery from firmware error (uint)
parm:           heart_beat_poll:Enable fw error detection periodic polling in msecs - Also set recovery_enable for this to be effective (uint)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.11.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[ath6kl_core]
ath6kl_p2p: 0
debug_mask: 0
heart_beat_poll: 0
recovery_enable: 0
suspend_mode: 0
testmode: 0
uart_debug: 0
uart_rate: 115200
wow_mode: 0

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    4.747569] ath6kl: Failed to init ath6kl core
[    4.753957] ath6kl_sdio: probe of mmc0:0001:1 failed with error -2
[    5.450587] mt7601u 1-2:1.0 wlx20e31707bec9: renamed from wlan0
[   12.623062] wlx20e31707bec9: authenticate with <MAC address>
[   12.643079] wlx20e31707bec9: send auth to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[   12.644638] wlx20e31707bec9: authenticated
[   12.645187] wlx20e31707bec9: associate with <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[   12.649121] wlx20e31707bec9: RX AssocResp from <MAC address> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[   12.679292] wlx20e31707bec9: associated
[   12.723394] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx20e31707bec9: link becomes ready
[  916.612331] wlx20e31707bec9: deauthenticating from <MAC address> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

########## wireless info END ############
```

This laptop only has one USB but I have to use it for WiFi dongle please if it has more I probably let it go.

Check the image what shown in windows please may be you get what kind of driver it needed.

https://intax.in/pic.png

Comment: No WiFi device has been identified by the script. Are you sure it's working?

Comment: in my window version but not in Ubuntu. dual boot wifi work fine show in bios also

Comment: So, the first thing you should do is disable Windows Fast Startup feature and shutdown (Windows) properly. Then boot Ubuntu and test. It should work "out-of-the-box", there are no user installable drivers for Atheros chips.

Comment: Nothing i think problem is with firmware creating a timeshift

Comment: Can I use those bin and sys for driver in https://intax.in/pic.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only thing need to do

Go to

https://github.com/qca/ath6kl-firmware

Find h3.0 & Select and copy to /lib/firmware/ath6k/

And restart (i restarted without any wireless dongle).

**And It work.**

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 23 Sep 2021 18:20 IST +0530

Booted last: 23 Sep 2021 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.11.0-36-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Sep 18 02:14:19 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, recovery, nomodeset, dis_ucode_ldr

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 114d:1000 Alpha Imaging Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:2819 Synaptics, Inc. Synaptics T Pad V 01.31
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5751 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

ath6kl_sdio            20480  0
ath6kl_core           167936  1 ath6kl_sdio
dell_laptop            24576  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,dell_laptop
cfg80211              888832  1 ath6kl_core
dell_wmi               20480  0
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
wmi_bmof               16384  0
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
sparse_keymap          16384  2 dell_wmi,intel_vbtn
wmi                    32768  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
video                  53248  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2176:d605:d52:73a7/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz' [AC1]>   
          Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search TOTOLINK

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         759       1  0 18:01 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Atheros Communications, Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath6kl_sdio
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.11.0-36-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               3.5.0.349-1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/INT33C6:00/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/mmc0:0001:1/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlan0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       c1e446a3-dda1-431d-ba14-8a9e3536d5ee
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.2/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          TOTOLINK
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 4294967295
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name = TOTOLINK
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.2
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::2176:d605:d52:73a7/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/3
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   c1e446a3-dda1-431d-ba14-8a9e3536d5ee | Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz

SSID                     BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 
Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz  <MAC 'Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz' [AC1]>  Infra  44    5220 MHz  270 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2      yes     *      

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/D-LINK_DIR-615.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=D-LINK_DIR-615 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=D-LINK_DIR-615
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/D-LINK_DIR-615 1.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=D-LINK_DIR-615 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=D-LINK_DIR-615
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DIRECT-cW-FireTV_2d93.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DIRECT-cW-FireTV_2d93 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=DIRECT-cW-FireTV_2d93
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

global
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2400 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5730 - 5850 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5850 - 5895 @ 40), (N/A, 27), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 71000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

phy#0
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2400 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5730 - 5850 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5850 - 5895 @ 40), (N/A, 27), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 71000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.22 GHz (Channel 44)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:5.22 GHz (Channel 44)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz' [AC1]>
                    Channel:44
                    Frequency:5.22 GHz (Channel 44)
                    Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Airtel_Zerotouch_5.8GHz"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000013278c2bd3
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1988ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[ath6kl_sdio]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl_sdio.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Atheros AR600x SDIO devices
depends:        ath6kl_core
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath6kl_sdio
vermagic:       5.11.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[ath6kl_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for AR600x SDIO and USB devices.
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath6kl_core
vermagic:       5.11.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug_mask:uint
parm:           suspend_mode:uint
parm:           wow_mode:uint
parm:           uart_debug:uint
parm:           uart_rate:uint
parm:           ath6kl_p2p:uint
parm:           testmode:uint
parm:           recovery_enable:Enable recovery from firmware error (uint)
parm:           heart_beat_poll:Enable fw error detection periodic polling in msecs - Also set recovery_enable for this to be effective (uint)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.11.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath6kl_core]
ath6kl_p2p: 0
debug_mask: 0
heart_beat_poll: 0
recovery_enable: 0
suspend_mode: 0
testmode: 0
uart_debug: 0
uart_rate: 115200
wow_mode: 0

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    5.514519] ath6kl: ar6004 hw 3.0 sdio fw 3.5.0.349-1 api 5
[    5.514530] ath6kl: firmware supports: 64bit-rates,map-lp-endpoint,ratetable-mcs15,no-ip-checksum
[    5.514869] ath6kl: Firmware lacks RSN-CAP-OVERRIDE, so HT (802.11n) is disabled.
[  251.034856] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```